# ActionScript 3.0: Loading external fonts (.ttf)

Tags: actionscript-3, fonts, truetype

Is it possible to load .ttf font from bytecode without using [embed] metatag or compiling font into .swf?
Situation next: My app gets zip archive with graphics, and I want to add chance to change visualization font.
But I can't use swf-compilation in that case. Instruments: FlexSDK, FLashDevelop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to use runtime loaded ttf/otf fonts is do the same that mxmlc do: transcode font files to AS3 classes, construct the new swf, load it into Loader and get fonts classes (that is embed ttf file into newly crated swf in runtime). You have to check the [swf spec](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/swf/pdf/swf_file_format_spec_v10.pdf) and I guess the [Flex SDK 4.6](http://sourceforge.net/adobe/flexsdk/wiki/Download%20Flex%204.6/) sources will be helpful. May be you will be able to find implementation, I can't managed to do this.

The still is the simple way - precompile each font file to swf and include it to your graphics zip, I don't this it's too hard even for non developer profession to click the bat file (you can make the template with as file and place the sdk and build bat file, all that artist need it's place the font file with the given name near the bat file, you event can ask in bat for the name of font and replace it in the template) :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually this isn't an answer, but I don't have enough reputation yet to add a comment.

I see the question is over a year old. Did the situation happen to change since then? For a VJ application I'm working on it would be nice if the users could just drop a TTF file in the resources directory to use it, rather than me having to make SWFs of all fonts that could be interesting to use - which would be way too time consuming anyway and will pose licensing issues I'd like to avoid.